Clarification about the decision to only allow outgoing connections flooding in erlay
I was reading the BIP-330 and saw that only the outgoing connections are low-fanout flooded.
A major idea is that we want that much of the nodes get the transaction in the first cycle itself, but since private nodes don't allow incoming connections, the only way they can get the transactions is through reconciliation . Won't this create an issue where public nodes have more transactions in their sketches than the private nodes almost every time, leading to the private nodes always lagging behind in their mempool?
